# Latest update to 8.7 with Commerce caused Edit buttons to appear in place of shipping/billing information

Tags: commerce

After updating core to 8.7, the input fields for shipping and billing information are now hidden and Edit buttons are in their place.  This has allowed users to checkout without entering shipping and billing information.  How can I show the required fields by default and get rid of the Edit button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have Commerce AutoSKU installed. The authors of the module modify one of Drupal's validation constraints which checks if fields are empty or not. This causes the addressbook form element to break, which what you're seeing, on top of other problems.

The issue is reported here, https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_autosku/issues/3086828

The solution is to either uninstall the commerce_autosku module *or* apply the patch in comment #3: https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2019-10-18/3086828-3.patch

Comment: What a wonderfully prompt and accurate answer, the issue is resolved.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @460des can you accept the answer (it helps show the question is resolved.) I also believe the patch should be merged soon and a release should be coming.

Comment: Oops.  This was my first question and I didn't realize about accepting. Tnx!